# How do you identify a specific selector in a multiple selector function?

Tags: jquery

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this question so apologies if it's unclear. I have this code which runs an AJAX query when any one of 3 dropdown menus are changed:

```
$('#ass-seenByName, #ass-seenByName1, #ass-seenByName2').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getMDSSpeciality.php",
    data: { "mds_name": $(this).val() },
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Hello " + msg);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        databaseError({
        title: "Database error",
        string: "Unable to get speciality for selected individual",
        file: window.location.pathname,
        actualError: errorThrown
        });
    } 
    }); 
});
```

The returned `msg` value needs to go to one of 3 fields which depends on the specific dropdown menu that was changed. My problem is I don't know how to get which of the 3 possible dropdown menus was changed in jQuery without duplicating this code block 3 times for each individual dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this` inside the event handler to refer the element which triggered the handler, so you can create a closure variable which will refer the element in the click handler which can be used in the success handler to set the message

```
$('#ass-seenByName, #ass-seenByName1, #ass-seenByName2').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getMDSSpeciality.php",
        data: {
            "mds_name": $(this).val()
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Hello " + msg);
            $this.html(msg)
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            databaseError({
                title: "Database error",
                string: "Unable to get speciality for selected individual",
                file: window.location.pathname,
                actualError: errorThrown
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't make this clear but I don't want the result to go into the same field as the selector. I want it to go to one of 3 completely different fields to the selectors, but the specific field it goes to depends on the selector used.

Comment: @Roy then you need to share how the 3 different fields can be found using the clicked element... a sample html markup will make it easier for us

Comment: Never mind Arun, I figured out I can use $this.attr('id') to get the id of the selector and then use a switch statement from there. Thanks for the help, I'll mark your answer as selected once I can!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use "this" and if you want to append to the options of the select,
try this,

```
$('#ass-seenByName, #ass-seenByName1, #ass-seenByName2').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getMDSSpeciality.php",
        data: {
            "mds_name": $(this).val()
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            $(this).empty();//empties the select 
            $(this).append($('<option>').text(msg).attr('value', msg));//appends to options            
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            databaseError({
                title: "Database error",
                string: "Unable to get speciality for selected individual",
                file: window.location.pathname,
                actualError: errorThrown
            });
        }
    });
});
```